# Storing domain files in subfolder

Tags: dns, directory

I'm often updating my website through various design iterations, and want to simplify my life by putting each version in its own folder: ie: www.mysite.com/v1.

How can I store all the contents of my in that folder (/v1, /v2, etc) yet have it accessed by simply typing in www.mysite.com.

I don't want just want to redirect the url, I want to remove the v1 from the url entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Apache, you could use mod_rewrite for this. Simply create a .htaccess file in the root of your public directory with a simple rewrite rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) v2/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will rewrite all URL's to the v2 directory. If you update your site to a new version, simply change v2 into something else and all requests will be rewritten to that directory.

Comment: But if there were a link to say: www.mysite.com/something

would that be redirected aswell? I've had this problem in the past.

Comment: Yes, it will. The entire requested path is appended to v2/